# Force all rows to take a value after a condition

Tags: python, pandas

I am working on a medium-sized dataframe and afer a lot of data manipulation I end up with the following DataFrame:

```
        id_1   id_2  flag_1  flag_2  flag_3
0       000d  5d238       0       0       0
1       001v  5cdd4       0       0       0
2       001v  5d36e       1       1       1
3       001v  5d53c       1       1       1
4       001c  5cc1a       1       0       0
...      ...    ...     ...     ...     ...
124809  003n  5d89f       0       0       0
124810  003n  5d8a6       1       0       0
124811  003n  5d8b1       1       1       0
124812  003n  5d8b3       1       1       1
124813  003n  5d8cc       1       1       1
```

Here's the code you can use to recreate the dataframe:

```
import pandas as pd
a = {'id_1':['000d','001v','001v','001v','001c','003n','003n','003n','003n','003n'],'id_2':['5d238','5cdd4','5d36e','5d35c','5cc1a','5d89f','5d8a6','5d8b1','5d8b3','5d8cc'],'flag_1':[0,0,1,1,1,0,1,1,1,1],'flag_2':[0,0,1,1,0,0,0,1,1,1],'flag_3':[0,0,1,1,0,0,0,0,1,1]}
pd.DataFrame(a)
```

I am trying to create a condition so that whenever a `1` appears in the column, all rows after that are forced to be `0`, for each unique id_1 and for each column independently.
I've tried using `groupby('id_1')['flag_1'].max()` to create an extra dataframe and later append it but it's not working (or I am most probably doing something wrong). I have also tried creating a list of unique id_1 values and then iterating over each of them to find the first row with value `1` and forcing all the other ones to `0`, and then repeat the loop for the other columns, but it proves very inefficient and time consuming.
My expected output is:

```
        id_1   id_2  flag_1  flag_2  flag_3
0       000d  5d238       0       0       0
1       001v  5cdd4       0       0       0
2       001v  5d36e       1       1       1
3       001v  5d53c       0       0       0
4       001c  5cc1a       1       0       0
...      ...    ...     ...     ...     ...
124809  003n  5d89f       0       0       0
124810  003n  5d8a6       1       0       0
124811  003n  5d8b1       0       1       0
124812  003n  5d8b3       0       0       1
124813  003n  5d8cc       0       0       0
```

Comment: Oh yes, I will fix that, I'm sorry. I changed some data to avoid disclosing private information.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can try this:

```
df.assign(**df.groupby('id_1')[cols].apply(lambda x: x.ne(1).shift().cumprod() * x).fillna(df))
```

Output:

```
   id_1   id_2 flag_1 flag_2 flag_3
0   00d  5d238      0      0      0
1  001v  5cdd4      0      0      0
2  001v  5d36e      1      1      1
3  001v  5d35c      0      0      0
4  001c  5cc1a      1      0      0
5  003N  5d89f      0      0      0
6  003N  5d8a6      1      0      0
7  003N  5d8b1      0      1      0
8  003N  5d8b3      0      0      1
9  003N  5d8cc      0      0      0
```

Basically, using `ne` and `cumprod` on each group.  When flag=1, ne(1) returns zero and use cumprod to keep zero.

Answer (score 2):

You can use [DataFrame.groupby](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.groupby.html) with [apply](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.core.groupby.GroupBy.apply.html):

```
df.groupby('id_1',as_index=False)['flag_1','flag_2','flag_3'].apply(lambda x:  (x.eq(1))&(x.shift(1).eq(0)) ).astype(int)
print(df)

   id_1   id_2  flag_1  flag_2  flag_3
0   00d  5d238       0       0       0
1  001v  5cdd4       0       0       0
2  001v  5d36e       1       1       1
3  001v  5d35c       0       0       0
4  001c  5cc1a       0       0       0
5  003N  5d89f       0       0       0
6  003N  5d8a6       1       0       0
7  003N  5d8b1       0       1       0
8  003N  5d8b3       0       0       1
9  003N  5d8cc       0       0       0
```

Comment: Add `as_index = False` to keep it.

Answer (score 1):

Here's one way:

```
# the flag columns
# can be df.filter(like='flag')
flags = df.iloc[:,2:]

# find the first 1.0 rows for each group
maxidx = flags.where(flags.eq(1)).groupby(df['id_1']).transform('idxmax')

# mask these rows with 1 else 0
df.iloc[:,2:] = np.where(flags.index.values[:,None] == maxidx, 1, 0)
```

Output:

```
   id_1   id_2  flag_1  flag_2  flag_3
0   00d  5d238       0       0       0
1  001v  5cdd4       0       0       0
2  001v  5d36e       1       1       1
3  001v  5d35c       0       0       0
4  001c  5cc1a       1       0       0
5  003N  5d89f       0       0       0
6  003N  5d8a6       1       0       0
7  003N  5d8b1       0       1       0
8  003N  5d8b3       0       0       1
9  003N  5d8cc       0       0       0
```